# How do I call abstract class' child class method when using an array of child objects?

Tags: java

I have an abstract class(parent class) and its child class.

In main, I created an array. It looks like this:

```
AbstractClass[] array = {childClassObj1, childClassObj2};
printInfo(array);

public static void printInfo (AbstractClass[] array){
System.out.printf("%s", childClassObj1.getInfo());
}
```

The compiler error occurs in "childClassObj1.getInfo()". If I change it to "array[0].getInfo()", it cannot be done since the method getInfo() is in the child class, not in the abstract class. How do I call abstract class' child class method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `abstract` method `getInfo()` to your parent class.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    public abstract String getInfo();
}
```

Then, override this method in your child class:

```
public class ChildClass extends AbstractClass {
    @Override
    public String getInfo() {
        return "Info string";
    }
}
```

Then, iterate over your array and call that method on each instance:

```
public static void printInfo (AbstractClass[] array){
    for(AbstractClass child : array) {
        System.out.printf("%s%n", child.getInfo());
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you can't add methods to your abstract class, you'll need to cast each element in your loop to the type of your child class:

```
public static void printInfo (AbstractClass[] array){
    for(AbstractClass child : array) {
        System.out.printf("%s%n", ((ChildClass)child).getInfo());
    }
}
```

Be careful though. This will only work if you're certain that only instances of `ChildClass` are inside your array. If there are instances of another sub-class you'll get a `ClassCastException`.

Also doing it like this kinda defeats the purpose of having an abstract class because you could easily use an array of `ChildClass` instead if you only need the functionality from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not allowed to add a method in the abstract class. Is there any other way?